# Использование метода в методе

Tags: java, android

Есть метод, в котором сравниваются ссылки одного объекта с другим:

```
    public boolean contains(ImageUpload newVideoUpload) {
    for (ImageUpload imageUpload : imageUploads) {
        if (imageUpload.getUrl().equals(newVideoUpload.getUrl()))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

И метод, в котором я работаю с id'шниками youtube(вытаскиваю id, после чего вставляю preview видео, где после отображаю на экране):

```
void getIdUrl(String url, int position) {
    String video_id = "";
    String expression = "";
    if (url != null && url.trim().length() > 0 && url.matches(".*\\byoutube\\b.*")) {
        expression = "^.*((youtu.be" + "\\/)" + "|(v\\/)|(\\/u\\/w\\/)|(embed\\/)|(watch\\?))\\??v?=?([^#\\&\\?]*).*";
        CharSequence input = url;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String groupIndex1 = matcher.group(7);
            if (groupIndex1 != null && groupIndex1.length() == 11)
                video_id = groupIndex1;
            ImageUpload imageUpload = new ImageUpload();
            imageUpload.setLoadImage(true);
            OutputMetadata outputMetadata = new OutputMetadata();
            outputMetadata.setVideoUrl("http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + video_id + "/0.jpg");
            outputMetadata.setFilename("http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + video_id + "/0.jpg");
            imageUpload.setOutputMetadata(outputMetadata);
            controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().add(imageUpload);
            adapterForm.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "This video already exists!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Вопрос в том, как использовать метод contains в методе getIdUrl.

Comment: В таком виде у Вас никак его использовать не получится, потому что тип объекта, который, в частности, содержит ссылку на превью, у Вас `ImageUpload`, а в методе `contains` – `VideoUpload`. Приведите их к одному знаменателю.

Comment: И небольшое замечание, судя по названию метода `getIdUrl(...)` он должен что-то возвращать.

Comment: сontains привёл в порядок(обновил вопрос).
насчёт замечание не совсем понял, что он должен возвращать.

Comment: Если Вы проверяете наличие элемента путем сравнения ссылок на полные видео, то лучше это сделать в самом начале метода, дабы не совершать лишние манипуляции, если объект уже содержится в списке. По замечанию, если в названии метода присутствует `get`, то, по логике, этот метод используется для получения чего-либо, то есть он должен что-то возвращать. Если он у Вас ничего не возвращает, то следует подумать о корректном названии метода в соответствии с его функционалом.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, можно изменить метод `contains(...)`:

```
public boolean contains(String url) {
    for (ImageUpload imageUpload : imageUploads) {
        if (imageUpload.getUrl().equals(url))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

А в методе `getIdUrl(...)` сначала проверять наличие объекта:

```
void getIdUrl(String url, int position) {
    if (ClassName.contains(url)) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

, где `ClassName`– имя класса, где определен метод `contains(...)`.

Comment: метод contains расположен в этом же фрагменте.
+ если я правильно понимаю, вместо ... после if (ClassName.contains(url)) {, будем добавлять еще дополнительно моих три if?

Comment: В блок после `if(...)`следует добавить код, который будет выполнятся в том случае, **если добавляемое видео уже есть в списке**. В блок после `else` нужно добавить код, который будет выполнятся в том случае, **если добавляемого видео в списке еще нет**.